# Typesetting molecular transition lines, like CO 5-4

Tags: mhchem

The `mhchem` lets me typeset molecules. But, I do not know how to properly typeset the energy levels important in spectroscopy.

For example, in [this paper](http://www2.mps.mpg.de/homes/rengel/mllfrhc-2012.pdf), section 2.1, we find the following:

```
H_2O(2_{21}-1_{10})
```

I can do it by hand, but maybe there is a more official way?

Comment: I'm not a chemist and I don't know the conventions on the notation of energy levels. Can you give the general rule for this?

Comment: I would imagine that doing it by hand is the official way.  I don't see any benefit doing it any other way for this particular example.

Comment: @Ruben I am not a chemist or spectroscopist either; I do not know the rule.  I'll ask around in the lab.

Comment: I'd simply write this directly: `\ce{H2O}($2_{21}$--$1_{10}$)`. (One _could_ of course write a macro for it... `\newcommand*\transition[2]{($#1$--$#2$)}` and then use `\ce{H2O}\transition{2_{21}}{1_{10}}`)

Comment: @clemens The link above is dead. Do you wanna convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B That would be nice, I would then be able to accept it.  I fixed the dead link in my question.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Niriel: done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply write this directly:

```
\ce{H2O}($2_{21}$--$1_{10}$)
```

One could of course write a macro for it, *e.g.*:

```
\newcommand*\transition[2]{($#1$--$#2$)}
```

and then use

```
\ce{H2O}\transition{2_{21}}{1_{10}})
```

in the document.